# Rational map over product of projective curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be a smooth projective curve given by a homogeneous polynomial $F \in k[X,Y,Z]$.
Im working with the rational map $\phi: C \times C \to \mathbb{P}^2$ such that
$$\phi([X_1,Y_1,Z_1] , [X_2,Y_2,Z_2]) = [Y_1Z_2 - Y_2 Z_1 , X_2Z_1 - X_1Z_2 , X_1Y_2 - X_2Y_1] $$ 
This coincide with the dual variety of $C$ when apply this map over the diagonal of $C\times C$. I need information about this map, someone knows where can I find some information ? (a book, paper...)